# Would there exist a symmetry around the mode in a truncated uni-modal distribution (which is differentiable)?

Tags: distributions, truncation, mode, symmetry

If we truncated around the mode of an asymmetric (continuous and differentiable) unimodal distribution, would there be a symmetry around the truncation point?

For example if X is generated from an asymmetric unimodal distribution, $f_{X}(a)$ the mode is located at point $m$ then there exit a $v$ such that $f_{X-m}(v)=f_{X-m}(-v)$

If no, why not? Was there a paper that mentions this?

If yes, why? Is there a paper that mentions this?

Comment: What kind of symmetry? It is very easy to come up with counterexamples...

Comment: symmetry around the mode (the only one mode)

Comment: Why would you expect the symmetry?

Comment: @Tim this is because we may find v small enough such that there is symmetry around the $X-m$

Comment: But this has nothing to do with truncation... You are simply arguing that as $v \to 0$ then $f_{X-m}(v) = f_{X-m}(-v)$...

Comment: @Tim yes but would there be v such that v is not particularly zero?

Comment: For *any* non-symmetric distribution? Again, you can easily come up with counterexamples (e.g. distribution where probability density dramatically drops on one side at the mode ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58468/discussion-between-rsc05-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

There is **no reason at all** to expect this. In short, given a unimodal distribution (on the real line), unless this distribution is symmetric around the mode at the outset, there will be some (finite, symmetric) interval around the mode such that the truncation of the distribution to that interval is asymmetric.

If the truncation of the distribution to all such intervals where symmetric, then the distribution itself would be symmetric.

Comment: Thank you but I did not say that the distribution to ALLsuch intervals. I said there will be some intervals around the mode that the distribution on this interval (might be super small) are symmetric. I hope this explains my point.